# configure F5 via Puppet

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, f5-big-ip

I have an Ubuntu PuppetMaster instance.

I need to manage a F5 BIG-IP (v10.2.4) device.

I'm following the directions for the Puppet Labs F5 module ( `http://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/f5` ).

Is it possible for the f5_proxy node to be co-located with the PuppetMaster server ?  Or need they be separate servers ?

Alternatively, perhaps I can perform my testing against a software F5 ( F5 Virtual Appliance ).  Is it possible to install Puppet Agent on a software F5 box ?

What are best practices here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My test experience has been no problems co-locating puppet master & agent on the same Ubuntu instance. This is because in `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf` the master and agent are configured separately. Just must make sure that network route is available so that the Ubuntu server can ssh to itself on port 8140.

Answer (score 2):

Because the F5 is based on Red Hat, you technically can install the puppet agent, but in order to do this, you would have to install the puppet agent itself and ruby which would break the support you would receive from F5, and this is therefore not recommended and best practice would be not to do this. If you have just a one off node, then you should consider just configuring the F5 directly. If you really have dozens of F5s that need configuring, you should consider using F5's native solutions - the [BIG-IQ](https://f5.com/products/big-iq/big-iq-device) (which F5 is moving towards) or the [Enterprise Manager](http://www.f5.com/pdf/products/enterprise-manager-overview.pdf) (which is the old way of doing configuration management for the F5s, which they are moving away from).

Finally, you can also manage the F5 via the [REST API for the F5](https://devcentral.f5.com/d/icontrol-rest-user-guide) which is a supported method of configuration management for this device.

(Source: I am Former Network Support Engineer for F5 and I worked out of the office which is developing the BIG-IQ)